# wall post using jquery and php

Tags: php

I want to make code for making comments and share it to others.
When I run this code and write a comment it prints nothing.
**Note**: I got this code from a tutorial on youtube.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>hesham</title>
</head>
<script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascrpt">
function get()
{
    var input = $('#cmt').val();
    $('#an').prepend(input);
};
</script>

<body>
<form name="frm">
<input type="text" name="cmt" id="cmt" /><input type="button" value="post" onclick="get()" />                 
</form>
<div id="an" style="width:300px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script should be inside the `<head>` (you closed the `<head>` first, and you should check the location of the jQuery declaration in your `<head>`.

Comment: - deleted original post. +1 @SableFoste,i read it too fast to see that. good catch.

Comment: Please ask a question properly, we understand it's not printing anything and want to help you - we don't need 4 exclamation marks followed by a "plz" in order to do so.

Comment: i put the script inside the head and there were nothing happen

Comment: Consult my answer below @user3513220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
<script type="text/javascrpt">
                          ^-- // missing the "i"
```

It's mispelled, a slight typo.

Change it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and it will work.

(tested)

You could also place your jQuery in `<head></head>` yet, my test worked either way.